# Google Sheet: Program a button to add/minus a calculated value to a column of cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-query

The Google Sheet used is [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WtJD__y4IxdWAzmawn7I-z7_w0HreBf2x6IvWq4k9Rw/edit?usp=drive_web).

Under "Medication Record" tab, there are two buttons with "+" and "-" sign.

I want to write a macro such that when I click on the "+" sign, the value of cell M4 gets added with a value of H4*x*y, where:

```
x = 1 if J4 = "od", "om" or "on"

= 2 if J4 = "bd"

= 3 if J4 = "td"

= 4 if J4 = "qd"

y = 7 if L4 = "Y"

= countif('Basic Info'!$B$17:$H$17,"x") if L4 = "N" (counting the number of x in the dialysis schedule under "Basic info" tab).
```

The same action would be done to all cells in the M column, from cell M4 downwards.

Similarly, if I click on the "-" button, a calculated value will be minus from a the cells from M4 downwards.

Really appreciate if someone could assist with writing the code since I am totally new to Google App Script.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hey, thanks for the notification. I have updated the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can create and image of a plus sign with the google slides or google drawing and download it to your computer.  I download them into my copy of google drive so it's available in google drive. You can then insert that image into the spreadsheet from the insert menu.  Then click on the down arrow and select assign script and give it the name of your script.  For testing sake you can put something like this in the script:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi.alert('This is the plus button');
```

When you click on the button you should see an alert dialog that say's "This is the plus button".  Go ahead and try to create you own script and if you have any trouble come back and we'll help.

You should take a look at the help menu in the script editor and click on tthe API Reference.  The documentation is pretty good.  Here's a [link to the spreadsheet section](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet).